# Help to understand AST notice period (Assured Shorthold Tenancy Agreement)

Tags: tenant

[image]

Here is the thing. I moved into the property on 25th August 2016.
I was told that after the first six months, if I do not give notice, it is assumed that I can continue to live (rent).

Now I'd like to move out and terminate the tenancy. Do I still have to give TWO months notice? How do I interpret

> This
>   Notice can only expire after the first six months of the Tenancy. (The Tenant agrees not to serve
>   such notice to fall due between 1st December and 15th January in any year)

Also, for 19.4

> To pay to the Agent £195+vat towards check-out administration costs at the end or sooner termination of the Tenancy.(This administration charge is reduced to £145+vat where total
>   duration of stay is 12 months or more

Can I agree to pay £145+vat to get a shorter notice? Say to terminate next week?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Yes, you have to give 2 months notice *and* you have to pay £145 + VAT

The first clause says your notice cannot end within 6 months of the start of the lease: that is long gone.

You pay the lower fee because you will have stayed longer than 12 months by the time your 2 months notice expires.

You can try to negotiate a shorter notice period - they have advantages in relenting if you move out earlier.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand this "This Notice can only expire..........". I thought this means I don't have to give two months notice now? I have now already lived for 12 months. September would be the 13th month. And the Tenancy is only for "one year", normally.

Comment: No; the section you quote means that you can't end the tenancy in the first 6 months, which is normal for an AST.